# How to make a method to wrap text in stars?

Tags: java

My goal is to add a method printStars to the program that prints a line of stars and use this method in the existing method write to print “Hello, World!” in a box made of stars, like so:

```
******************* 
** Hello, World! ** 
*******************
```

I have the following code for now but it just prints a line above and below the Hello World.
I'd also want to have a case where it outputs the following:

```
******************* 
***             *** 
**               ** 
*  Hello, World!  * 
**               ** 
***             *** 
*******************
```

Have this code for now but it doesn't really wrap the String "Hello, World". It just prints a line of stars above and below.

```
public class StarWriter {
    /**
     * yk prints stars
     */
    void printStars(int n) {
        for(int i=1; i <= 14; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Say hello
     */
    void writeBox() {    

        printStars(15);
        printStars(2);
        System.out.println("\nHello World");
        printStars(2);
        printStars(15);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StarWriter().writeBox();
    }
}
```

Comment: You always print 14 stars, instead of input - `n`. Then fix your new lines and you will get the first required output. About the second, i advise you to make an attempt and then ask about what didn't work. As a second advice, learn to use your IDE's debugger to inspect the program flow, it makes finding errors much easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems.

1. Use the parameter argument in the `printStars` method (hardcoded to 14)
2. Emit new lines after each line and ONLY after each line
3. Pad the string with spaces where expected

So...

```
void printStars(int n) {
  // changed to standard index handling (i.e. base-0)
  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
  }
}
```

... and ...

```
void writeBox() {    
  printStars(15);
  System.out.println();

  printStars(2);
  // replace println with print, remove newline-character, pad with spaces
  System.out.print(" Hello World ");
  printStars(2);
  System.out.println();

  printStars(15);
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`printStars` does not move to the next line after printing

So, when you call `printStars(15)` and `printStars(2)`, it will simply print 17 stars in 1 line

Utilize `System.out.println()` to make a new line

```
void writeBox() {    

    printStars(15);
    System.out.println();
    printStars(2);
    System.out.print("Hello World");
    printStars(2);
    System.out.println();
    printStars(15);

}
```

It is now unnecessary to have `println` and `\n` in the `Hello World` statement

Also, make sure to change `i <= 14` to `i <= n` in `printStars`

Comment: That explains why the askers code doesn't work, but it doesn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StarWriter {
    private static final int BORDER = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Hello world!\nI am here!";
        String[] lines = text.split("\n");

        int maxLength = 0;
        for (String line : lines) if (line.length() > maxLength) maxLength = line.length();
        int fullLength = maxLength + BORDER * 2;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String starsOnly = fill(fullLength, '*') + "\n";
        builder.append(starsOnly);
        for (int i = BORDER; i >= 1; i--) addStars(maxLength, builder, i);
        for (int i = 1; i <= BORDER; i++) addStars(maxLength, builder, i);
        builder.append(starsOnly);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            String line = lines[i];
            int index = (BORDER + i) * (fullLength + 1) + BORDER;
            builder.replace(index, index + line.length(), line);
        }

        String result = builder.toString();

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static void addStars(int maxLength, StringBuilder result, int i) {
        String stars = fill(i, '*');
        result.append(stars).append(fill(maxLength + (BORDER - i) * 2, ' ')).append(stars).append("\n");
    }

    private static String fill(int amount, char c) {
        return new String(new char[amount]).replaceAll("\0", "" + c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since others are posting their work, I'll post mine.

The general way to solve any problem like this is to break it down into smaller and smaller steps until you can simply code each step.

What I did was break the problem down this way.

1. Determine if I want the simple stars or the fancy stars.
2. Write a method to create a line of a character, either a star or a blank.
3. Write a method to create the simple stars.
4. Test the code
5. Write a method to create the fancy stars.
6. Test the code.

I used the `StringBuilder` class extensively because the `append` method can take characters, strings, and other `StringBuilder` instances as input.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
/*
 * The purpose of the class is to write text inside a box, like this:
 * 
 * ******************* 
 * ** Hello, World! ** 
 * *******************
 * 
 * The fancyWrap flag, when true, will produce a fancier star wrap, like this:
 * 
 * ******************* 
 * ***             *** 
 * **               ** 
 * *  Hello, World!  * 
 * **               ** 
 * ***             *** 
 * *******************
 */

public class StarWrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String output = new StarWrap(true).wrapStars("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    private final boolean isFancyWrap;

    public StarWrap(boolean isFancyWrap) {
        this.isFancyWrap = isFancyWrap;
    }

    public String wrapStars(String text) {
        if (isFancyWrap) {
            return fancyWrap(text);
        } else {
            return simpleWrap(text);
        }
    }

    private String fancyWrap(String text) {
        int length = text.length() + 6;
        char star = '*';
        char blank = ' ';

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(createLine(length, star));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append(createLine(3, star));
        builder.append(createLine(text.length(), blank));
        builder.append(createLine(3, star));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append(createLine(2, star));
        builder.append(createLine(text.length() + 2, blank));
        builder.append(createLine(2, star));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append(star);
        builder.append(createLine(2, blank));
        builder.append(text);
        builder.append(createLine(2, blank));
        builder.append(star);
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append(createLine(2, star));
        builder.append(createLine(text.length() + 2, blank));
        builder.append(createLine(2, star));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append(createLine(3, star));
        builder.append(createLine(text.length(), blank));
        builder.append(createLine(3, star));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append(createLine(length, star));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String simpleWrap(String text) {
        int length = text.length() + 6;
        char star = '*';
        char blank = ' ';

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(createLine(length, star));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append(createLine(2, star));
        builder.append(blank);
        builder.append(text);
        builder.append(blank);
        builder.append(createLine(2, star));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        builder.append(createLine(length, star));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private StringBuilder createLine(int length, char c) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            builder.append(c);
        }

        return builder;
    }

}
```